# Return text between brackets and not include brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regEx to match text in brackets:

```
'textA(textB)'.match(/\((.+?)\)/g)
```

But it returns text including the brackets e.g. (textB)

How do I return the text without the brackets e.g. textB

Comment: I've updated my answer in case you care about avoiding matching things like "text)" without a `(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the input contains balanced parenthesis. If yes, then you  could use the below regex to match all characters which are present within the brackets.

```
[^()]+(?=\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kX9tQ2/2)

```
> 'textA(textB)'.match(/[^()]+(?=\))/g)
[ 'textB' ]
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^()]+` Negated character class which matches any character but not of `(` or `)` one or more times.
- `(?=\))` positive lookahead which asserts that the matched characters must be followed by a closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: Won't this also match "textA" in `"textA)"`? The regular expression does not ensure that the match has an open parenthesis at the start.

Comment: @Pointy i assume that the input contains balanced paranthesis.

Comment: Well I don't :) Nothing like that was mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Then you can be helpful by making the assumption part of the answer. That way anyone looking for an answer knows if it applies to their situation.

Comment: This is a good pattern nevertheless, because it makes the "g" qualifier work. I'm not sure how to construct an expression that would work with the "g" qualifier and *not* match strings without opening parentheses however.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Please consider offering an breakdown explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly include the parentheses in the regular expression by quoting them with `\`

```
'textA(textB)'.match(/\((.+?)\)/g)
```

If you don't do that, the outer parentheses are interpreted as regex metacharacters.

To extract the matched text without the surrounding parentheses:

```
var match = 'textA(textB)'.match(/\((.+?)\)/); // no "g"
var text = match[1];
```

It's tricky to create a regular expression that works with the "g" ("global") qualifier to match and collect the strings within parentheses, because that qualifier causes the `.match()` function return value to change. Without "g", the `.match()` function returns an array with the overall match in position 0 and the matched groups in subsequent positions. However, *with* the "g", `.match()` simply returns all matches of the entire expression.

The only way I can think of is to repeatedly match, and the easiest way to do that (in my opinion) is with a function:

```
var parenthesized = [];
var text = "textA (textB) something (textC) textD) hello (last text) bye";
text.replace(/\((.+?)\)/g, function(_, contents) {
    parenthesized.push(contents);
});
```

That will accumulate the properly-parenthesized strings "textB", "textC", and "last text" in the array. It will not include "textD" because it is not properly parenthesized.

Comment: this includes brackets in the output - not quite what I'm looking for, but thanks for attempting

Comment: @MarzSocks It includes brackets in the overall match - that's not avoidable. It does not include brackets in the captured group. I'll add an explanation.

Comment: this `console.log(/\((.+?)\)/.exec('textA(textB)')[1])` should work. Why you don't use the g modifier?

Comment: @AvinashRaj because the "g" modifier causes the return value of `.match` to change. I'll add more to the answer.

Comment: but without g, it won't do a global match.

Comment: Why not `exec` in a while loop?

Comment: @nhahtdh that would work too; I personally just like the `.replace` approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a function which matches a string against a regex and customize the output array via a user-defined function.

```
String.prototype.matchf = function (re, fun) {
    if (re == null || re.constructor != RegExp) {
        re = new RegExp(re);
    }

    // Use default behavior of String.prototype.match for non-global regex.
    if (!re.global) {
        return this.match(re);
    }

    if (fun == null) { // null or undefined
        fun = function (a) { return a[0]; };
    }

    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw TypeError(fun + " is not a function");
    }

    // Reset lastIndex
    re.lastIndex = 0;
    var a;
    var o = [];

    while ((a = re.exec(this)) != null) {
        o = o.concat(fun(a));
    }

    if (o.length == 0) {
        o = null;
    }

    return o;
}
```

The user-defined function is supplied with an array, which is the return value of [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

The user-defined function is expected to return a value or an array of values. It can return an empty array to exclude the content of the current match from the resulting array.

The behavior of the custom function above should be the same as `String.match` when user-defined function `fun` is not supplied. This should have less overhead compared to abusing `String.replace` to extract an array, since it doesn't have to construct the replaced string.

Back to your problem, using the custom function above, you can write your code as:

```
'textA(textB)'.matchf(/\((.+?)\)/g, function (a) {return a[1];});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `matchAll` function instead. Maybe?

(your original regular expression was good enough for this)

```
for (const results of 'textA(textB)'.matchAll(/\((.+?)\)/g)) {
    console.log(results[0]) // outputs: (textB)
    console.log(results[1]) // outputs: textB
}
```

OR

```
const results = [...'textA(textB)(textC)'.matchAll(/\((.+?)\)/g)];
console.log(results) // outputs array of each result
```

The `matchAll()` method returns an iterator of all results matching a string against a regular expression, including capturing groups;
index 0 returns the whole, and indexes after return group parts.